# Using the WebGrid format parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, format, webgrid

I am not using MVC.  This is a C# Asp.Net Web Pages project.  There is no view/model/controller.  All of my searching has only found references to eg: HTML.ActionLink

I'm trying to use the WebGrid.Column.format parameter to make a link.  I need to use some of the data fields from the query.

This works:

```
anchorGrid.Column(columnName: "Latitude", header: @Sorter("Latitude", "Latitude", anchorGrid), style: "alignRight nowrap", format: (item) => Html.Raw(item.Latitude.ToString("F5"))),
```

Using that same datafield again, I have tried the following:

```
anchorGrid.Column(header: "Map", format: (item) => Html.Raw("<a href='http://maps.google.com/?q=@(item.Latitude.ToString("F5")),@(item.Longitude.ToString("F5"))'>Map</a>")),

anchorGrid.Column(header: "Map", format: (item) => <text><a href='http://maps.google.com/?q=@(item.Latitude.ToString("F5")),@(item.Longitude.ToString("F5"))'>Map</a></text>),

anchorGrid.Column(header: "Map", format: (item) => Html.Raw("<a href='http://maps.google.com/?q=" + item.Latitude.ToString("F5") + ","+ item.Longitude.ToString("F5") + "'>Map</a>")),
```

and a few variations to do with brackets and @ symbols.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `Html.Raw` in the format parameter as the WebGrid helper spits out HTML anyway. You only need to prefix the HTML you want to output with an `@` sign:

```
anchorGrid.Column(header: "Map", format: @<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=@(item.Latitude.ToString("F5")),@(item.Longitude.ToString("F5"))">Map</a>"),
```

Comment: Please provide some context around your answer.

Comment: Sorry, forgot where I was :)